# Why does my code give the incorrect answer?

Tags: python

I have only very recently began to learn python or any programming language but I am struggling to understand why a piece of code behaves how it does.

I am following a course and in the course we are trying to create an app that determines if a number is odd or even.

This is what I wrote initially. I did this as I want to check that number % 2 was giving me the correct information - extremely new and just trying to understand the code I am using.

This failed

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))

check = print(number % 2)

if check == 0:
    print("This is an even number")
else:
    print("This is an odd number")
```

However, when I removed print it worked as expected.

```
number = int(input("Which number do you want to check? "))

check = number % 2

if check == 0:
    print("This is an even number")
else:
    print("This is an odd number")
```

I was just curious as to why this might be?

Thank you!

Comment: Why would the result of `print` be meaningful here? Pay close attention to what you're assigning `check` *from*. Consider: `check = ...` and then `print(check)` on the next line. Key point: `x = y` and `x = f(y)` are two *entirely* different things.

Answer (score 1):

The result of the `print` function is always `None`. `None == 0` will *always* be false.